# Fanout on root fails when doing concurrent transaction on unrelated property

Tags: firebase

The code below shows the minimum example where we see the bug. As you can see, the fanout `test/channels/sameKey/chats/${key}` while the transaction updates `test/user_phone_numbers/${key}`.

If I'm understanding transaction and update correctly, these two don't overlap so it should be safe to run concurrently. However, as soon as two concurrent requests come in, Firebug errors out with `[Error: set]`.

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

const firebaseRootRef = new Firebase(process.env.FIREBASE_URL)

const random = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max)

let key = 0
const nextKey = () => ++key % 2

const fanout = key => {

  const fanout = {
    [`test/channels/sameKey/chats/${key}`]: random(1000)
  }
  return firebaseComponent.update(firebaseRootRef, fanout)
}

const transaction1 = key => firebaseRootRef.child('test/user_phone_numbers/' + key)
  .transaction(_userId => !_userId ? random(100000) : undefined)

server.get('/', (req, res) =>
  transaction1(nextKey())
    .then(() => fanout(key))
    .then(() => res.send(200))
    .catch(e => {console.log(e); res.send(501)})
)

server.listen(3001, function () {
   console.log('incoming.controller listening on port 3001!');
});
```

The apache benchmark command to replicate:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 2 -r http://localhost:3001/
```

Comment: Here's a complete repo with package.json for testing this quickly: https://github.com/morgs32/firebase-bug

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug, it's working as intended. I ran into this several months back and here's the official response they gave me (emphasis mine).

> The issue here are transactions in combination with update calls.
>   **We'll abort any transactions at, below or above the path in any set or
>   update call**. So while the transaction is technically unaffected by
>   your update call at /venues/1, we still go ahead and cancel the
>   transaction. We know this is not optimal and we're looking into
>   improving this with a future release. One workaround is to defer the
>   update calls until the transactions have completed, or keep the
>   data in an entirely different subtree. The simplest workaround
>   might be to move all the writes in the update call into separate set
>   calls, which will not abort the transaction.

Comment: It's meant to error out? Were you seeing this `Error: set`? Also, in the OP's code he IS deferring the update until the transaction completes. Thanks for sharing their response by the way.

Comment: In that one process, yes. But not when his benchmark runs it concurrently.

Comment: I thought that was what you meant, just checking. One more thing, can you elaborate on keeping the data in a different subtree? Or point me in the direction of some literature, etc?

Comment: I think the better solution is to not update the root ref. Using a fanout at `test/channels` would circumvent the issue.